# Upgrade to SQL Server 2017 from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: upgrade, sql-server-2008-r2

I want upgrade my server to SQL Server 2017 from SQL Server 2008 R2(version 10.50.1600.1)
but upgrade rules failed on **SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack3 or later is required** [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMv0B.png)

Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack3 has this error: 
**The installed SQL Server product version is 10.50.1600.1, and the expected SQL Server version is 10.0.1600.22.**
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6aXN.png)

Upgrading to SQL Server 2014 has similar problem (Failed SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack2 or later is required)

How can upgrade to SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to tell you but the problem is as easy as you not reading numbers.

The last error message says it all:

The installed SQL Server product version is 10.50.1600.1, and the expected SQL Server version is 10.0.1600.22

As per https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/:

- The installed product is SQL Server 2008 R2.
- You try to install a SQL Server 2008 service pack. NOT R2. 10.0.1600.22 actually is SQ Server 2008, NOT R2, RTM version.

So, you just have the wrong service pack.

Comment: Oh....I'm sorry ...I have to be more careful....Thank you