# SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 >> SP3 Upgrade issue

Tags: sql-server

When I use

`select @@version`

then I get:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)
>
> Jun 17 2011 00:57:23
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>
> Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)

But in Control Panel I see that yesterday I have installed 10.53.6000.34

Yesterday after upgrade I restart entire Windows.

**Question:**
So my question is why does select @@version return me information that I still have SP1?

**btw.**

I saw this question:
[Upgrade to SQL Server 2017 from SQL Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/998842/upgrade-to-sql-server-2017-from-sql-server-2008-r2)

I also check:
https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

and I think that I use proper upgrade pack/installer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because [support for SQL Server 2008 has ended](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/support/sql/end-support-sql-server-2008).

Comment: For this reason, I wanted to update the database of "my new client".
Unfortunately, this was not possible due to the error I described.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using SQL 2K8 long time, but you could compare the @@version output with this simple query:

SELECT
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition

The product level should be SP3.

Comment: i belive you should consider a newer version of the sql server?

Comment: Finnally we install SQL 2019 Express on brand new machine.